# Python: Display output in all caps with a period after each character

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7.6

I'm trying to write a Python code that will display the output as all CAPS with a period in between each character and after the last.  no spaces.

Here is my code:

```
    initials = raw_input("What are your initials? ")

    print initials[0].upper(),".",initials[1].upper(),".",initials[2].upper(),"."
```

Let's say the users initials are 'ajl'

The ending output after user has input their initials is:

Output:  A . J . L .

How do I get it do output with no spaces between the characters??

Answer (score 1):

Use `".".join()` instead, and append the trailing dot:

```
print ".".join(initials.upper()) + "."
```

You could also only slightly modify your answer:

```
print initials[0].upper()+"."+initials[1].upper()+"."+initials[2].upper()+"."
```

Just replace `,` by `+`

Answer (score 1):

Below should work:

print ('.'.join(list(initials.upper())) + '.')

Comment: to split the string to chars

Comment: @user1898070 `list` is not neccessary, `join()` takes an iterable and the string already is an iterable. See my solution below.

Comment: Correct. Your solution is much better. List is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
...
initials = initials.upper()#instead of calling upper for each char.
print "%s.%s.%s." % (initials[0],initials[1],initials[2])
```

another (probably better since it supports any number of initials) way to do it would be:

```
src = 'xyz' #use input instead but for sake of showing.
initials = ''
for x in src.upper():
    initials += x + '.'
print initials
```

(see: http://pythonfiddle.com/so-jan-twentyeighth)

Comment: That will work, but I think it might be too complicated for this simple usecase. Also , you forgot the trailing dot ;-)